# Sending transactions through ethers and Metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, react

I want to send transaction via ethers and wallet connected to metamask with following code:

```
 async redeemAllocation(idoId: number) {
    const IRoot = new ethers.utils.Interface(JSON.stringify(RootAbi))
    const addrRoot = "0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0"
    const smcRoot = new ethers.Contract(addrRoot, IRoot)
    const investorIndex = await smcRoot.investorIndexFromProject(await this.signer!.getAddress(), idoId);
    let project = await smcRoot.projectById(idoId);
    const amount = project.amounts[investorIndex];

    const data = IRoot.encodeFunctionData("redeemAllocation", [idoId, amount]);

    this.signer!.sendTransaction({to: addrRoot, data: data}).then(async (tx) => {
      console.log('transaction sended')
  
      project = await smcRoot.projectById(idoId);
      console.log(project.redeemed[investorIndex])
    });
```

And get an error saying `Errors encountered in param 1: Invalid value "0x-a1a" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/0: QUANTITY, Invalid value "0x-a1a" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/1: { blockNumber: QUANTITY }, Invalid value "0x-a1a" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/2: { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined }, Invalid value "0x-a1a" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/3: "earliest" | "latest" | "pending"`.

`redeemAllocation` abi:

```
  {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "projectId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "amount",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "redeemAllocation",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
```

I guess the problem can be in `IRoot.encodeFunctionData`, but still don't get the reason clearly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your error is this, but Interface constructor gets an ABI without a parse. It doesn't need a JSON.parse every time for ABI.

```
Change this:
const IRoot = new ethers.utils.Interface(JSON.stringify(RootAbi))

To this:
const IRoot = new ethers.utils.Interface(RootAbi)
```

Source:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/